# Find type alias based on its property value in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write some types for executing Cloud Functions. I have a bunch of types like that, each in a separate file.

```
export type TAddRegistration = {
  name: 'addRegistration'
  data: TAddRegistrationData
  result: TAddRegistrationCallResult
}
```

```
export type TSignIn = {
  name: 'signIn'
  data: TSignInData
  result: TSignInCallResult
}
```

Now ultimately, I want to have a function in client-side code like this and based on passed function name it should provide correct data and result types.

```
function useCloudFunction(name: TFunctionName) {
  return (data: TFunctionData): TFunctionResult => {
     ...
  }
}
```

---

The first step is to declare TFunctionName. This approach works and I am not aware of a better one.

```
export type TFunctions = TAddRegistration | TSignIn
export type TFunctionName = Pick<TFunctions, 'name'>['name']
```

The second step is how to discover proper type alias based on the `name` argument passed into the function and that's where I am stumbling in the dark. Some sort of opposite "Pick" that can lookup in the `TFunctions` alias.

I can surely structure those aliases differently if there is some nicer way how to approach this.

### **Update:**

[This playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBBAJlgSsAcwEsBnGKAQxiIgDsARKiuAXjgG8BYAKDjjAAWdYAC44ZKEVoEeAXx6hIsBMlSYc+YhKo1aAYQoAbQ-hIBXQ-Dbt53RdHhIU6AMpECtAJIMmrDjz5gAFsKIkMxCSkZblt7ZSc1Nw9vA2NTCysOWwVwBxVnNCSvWj8uXjhaCiDROAByEndi2oC4LCYxQsbvRhgKFqhgc0sOopSjE0GMuR4cpUdVdGw8QlJyHTpSlsrqsVqKDRXtajpm8rbejqXNVcpjn17+yeHFg601u9SJoZhp7lm8hLoABiZloAGM7iQ-J1kiUAD4vZZvW66f7xBZoEHgu4AOSqqDYAAUiGCANYAHkxoIhuhIABo4AAibbARkAPgA2sz8YyALozbgAM2pdzgZhIwCxNLoAAoWR0pbj8QBKfzlQFU8F+ACiIDWEMpitpDPYFXxYgSEEFZuqcFkbMeMDMUBKMvOFAV1K57r5ys94K5A2+fNYbLVfD4AydLqZjJatmy3HFkpFuhljIasMZyplpsEwjEjMZdtVAHpS+IhBYsHAAEaoSAkBq1wyoGAQMUSuDBUKGOB0QyIOACYADIA) is probably the closest I could get, but not exactly desired outcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define your types like this:

```
type TFunctions = TSignIn | TAddRegistration
function useFunction<N extends TFunctions["name"]>(name: N) {
  type TFunc = Extract<TFunctions, { name: N }>
  return (data: TFunc["data"]): TFunc["result"] => {
    return ""; // impl?!
  }
}
```

You don't need `Pick<TFunctions, "name">["name"]` because that's equivalent to `TFunctions["name"]`.  Other than that the only difference between your original code and mine is that mine is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in `N`, the type of the `name` parameter.  This allows the compiler to remember *which* value `name` is, and strongly type the return type:

```
const signIn = useFunction("signIn");
const signInCallResult = signIn({ email: "okay" }); // TSignInCallResult
signIn({ phone: "oops" }); // error! needs TSignInData
const addReg = useFunction("addRegistration");
const addRegCallResult = addReg({ phone: "okay" }); // TAddRegistrationCallResult
addReg({ email: "oops" }) // error! needs TAddRegistrationData
```

Looks good to me.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=35&ssc=63&pln=29&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBBAJlgSsAcwEsBnGKAQxiIgDsARKiuAXjgG8BYAKDjjAAWdYAC44ZKEVoEeAXx6hIsBMlSYc+YhKo1aAYQoAbQ-hIBXQ-Dbt53RdHhIU6AMpECtAJIMmrDjz5gAFsKIkMxCSkZblt7ZSc1Nw9vA2NTCysOWwVwBxVnNCSvWj8uXjhaCiDROAByEndi2oC4LCYxQsbvRhgKFqhgc0sOopSjE0GMuR4cpUdVdGw8QlJyHTpSlsrqsVqKDRXtajpm8rbejqXNVcpjn17+yeHFg601u9SJoZhp7h4E9AAMTMtAAxncSH5OskSgAfF7LN63XQ8ABmIPBujgZhIwGBYLuAB4AHJwUAwYC0LCQtD4zF0EgAbQARNtgMyALoAPgAFGyxMSAJT+coA2kYvwAURAa3BhPFBN0JAANBwKlUaqTZFzHjAzFASjzzhQOnSWcbOYLTRiWQNvpzWFyRXw+AM9Qa4MzmQBuOAAej9cCIQTAhgA-ABCFq2bLcUEM+ANGF+HF4jF3HnMpPFZmC708eO0MjiLr6cbpSx+bPeHnsMkhMJiZkQADWFEQzLgsjz-sD0OKnwrP241dotf4QloNWbEDAJE73d9AbJUCg0AjFWAwGprlLPT6cYTcH2iJTuLpGeZJ+uR10ufzh6L8GvhEHT0yL4I48EwibrfbC49su6iIjc6xlmk748J+47BKE4SehAs7zl2wrLsAq7rpu240lchzvLo+5AA)

Comment: That's amazing. So close to the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a better way, but something like this would work:

```
type SpecialFunction<T> = T extends TSignIn['name'] ? TSignIn
  : T extends TAddRegistration['name'] ? TAddRegistration
  : never;

function useFunction<T extends TFunctionName>(name: T) {
  return (data: SpecialFunction<T>['data']): SpecialFunction<T>['result'] => {
    return ""
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=25&ssc=1&pln=33&pc=2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBBAJlgSsAcwEsBnGKAQxiIgDsARKiuAXjgG8BYAKDjjAAWdYAC44ZKEVoEeAXx6hIsBMlSYc+YhKo1aAYQoAbQ-hIBXQ-Dbt53RdHhIU6AMpECtAJIMmrDjz5gAFsKIkMxCSkZblt7ZSc1Nw9vA2NTCysOWwVwBxVnNCSvWj8uXjhaCiDROAByEndi2oC4LCYxQsbvRhgKFqhgc0sOopSjE0GMuR4cpUdVdGw8QlJyHTpSlsrqsVqKDRXtajpm8rbejqXNVcpjn17+yeHFg601u9SJoZhp7lm8hLoABiZloAGM7iQ-J1kiUAD4vZZvW66f7xBZoEHgu4AOSqqDYAAUiGCANYAHkxoIhuhIABo4AAibbARkAPgA2sz8YyALozbiAlwoMFEIxYml0Sls6FwUAwYC0LBQmHFDm1Fm1XlwAD8ri6tBaHTlIAVSpVV0O7106s12r16iRN3WhvKYlowAAbsAoABuAUAM2pdzgZhIwAld0pJrNyuBwd0eOqbIAFCyOgBKfzlAYwMxQEop84UMTC4Ci8UJqVoTm1YtajOlkViwyR3TS9UDb5a1gysp8Pi5-MlRmMlq2bLcMMRqu0FOMhqwxkZlPsfhCD1iUdwWRZgD0e-EQgsWDgACNUJASA0z4ZUDAIKHw3KQmE4HRDIg4AIfcAgA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer as well, pretty much the same as from @jcalz.

Comment: Actually, it isn't the same. Your approach does not account for "many" functions. Doing conditional type to account for eg. 10 functions would be ... 